# SQL Server Stored Procedures Insertar campos de una consulta en un campo de una tabla

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedure

Actualmente encuentro en un proyecto de syncronización de datos, y para ello necesito grabar el contenido de una tabla en un campo text separados por como ejemplo

El Resultado del Select

```
id    Nombre    Telefono     Dirección
1     Pedro     3710793      La Casa morada con techo azul
```

Hacer select a la tabla convertirlo en un campo separados por coma Ejemplo:

```
@texto = '1,Pedro,Perez,La Casa morada con Techo azul'
```

y el valor del texto insertarlo en otra tabla

```
Insert into tablaDestino (id, Datos, fecha, status) 
values ('5', @texto, SYSDATETIME(), '1')
```

Importante es que debo hacerlo en SQL Server 2008 R2 con Stored Procedures y Triggers

Comment: Me parece que tienes un problema más grande de lo que estás explicando. Podría darte una solución a esto basado en el DelimitedSplit8k, pero creo que sería mejor dar unos pasos atrás y reevaluar como se está haciendo la sincronización.

Comment: No se comprende bien tu pregunta, quieres sicronizar datos de una tabla a otra tabla dentro de la misma base de datos, a otra base de datos?